# Where condition check with session data userid is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Am trying get some data from the database to display using foreach . but the where condition is not working.

i need to display contents from table tbl_cart by checking the value of user_id in tbl_cart is equl to the stored session data id

> table users
>   [image]
>
> table tbl_cart

[image]

> login data (session data) please view here to know how i set the session

```
       public function login(){
        $data = array();
        if($this->session->userdata('success_msg')){
        $data['success_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('success_msg');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('success_msg');
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('error_msg')){
        $data['error_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('error_msg');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('error_msg');
    }
            if($this->input->post('loginSubmit')){
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 
                'required|valid_email');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 
              'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $con['returnType'] = 'single';
            $con['conditions'] = array(
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'status' => '1'
            );
            $checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con);
            if($checkLogin){
                $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
                $this->session-
            >set_userdata('userName',$checkLogin['name']);
                 $this->session-
            >set_userdata('UserEmail',$checkLogin['email']);
                // redirect('users/account/');
                 redirect('users/one/');

            }else{
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try 
 again.';
            }
        }
```

> controller

```
      public function oneusercart(){
        $data = array();
         if($this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn')){
        $data['user'] = $this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session-
        >userdata('userId')));
        //load the view
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart 
       where user_id= $this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session-
       >userdata('userId')))' );


      $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();


     $this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/head');
    $this->load->view('one/usercart', $resultdata);
    $this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/footer');
    $this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/script');
   }else{

        redirect('users/login');
    }
  }
```

Comment: just looking at the sql in the function `oneusercart` - it looks like there is a quotes issue with nested single quotes

Comment: can u please explain ?

Comment: PHP variables will not evaluate within single quotes - so the sql does not actually fetch anything from PHP as you are attempting but includes `$this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('userId')))` as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $query will be like this please try this

```
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart 
   where user_id= '.$this->session->userdata('userId'));
```

Comment: is it possible to change the status to zero on  a specific row in the tbl_cart ??

Comment: what do you want to do i do not get it? can you elaborate your problem once again?

Comment: I need to display all the data from tbl_cart where status=1 and id = session id, and also need to remove data from the display by change the status to -0 . this i need to perform

Comment: $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart 
   where user_id= '.$this->session->userdata('userId').'AND status=1' );

Comment: i think you have to do like this